# debug-ignored-errors --> suppress an annoying error/false-positives

Tags: debugging

In my emacs, i have set `(debug-on-error t)` to see the error's stacktrace. It is very helpful but for mundane errors, it becomes annoying...
One such error is,

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer")
  read-from-minibuffer("Goto line: " nil nil nil nil ("1"))
```

Emacs has provided a way to suppress `backtrace prints` on such errors using the variable, `debug-ignored-errors`. It takes a list of error codes. Say for the error that the variable has no value - the code is `'(void-variable)`.

Where do i find the error codes for all the other stacktrace messages?

Comment: For this particular error, if you'd like Emacs not to stop you from using the minibuffer while in minibuffer, you can set `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to `t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`debug-ignored-errors` can hold signal names (e.g. `user-error`) but also regular expressions.  So try:

```
(push "\\`Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer"
      debug-ignored-errors)
```

But you might also like to report this issue as a bug.  This error should probably be changed to a `user-error` so you don't need to change `debug-ignored-errors` yourself.

Comment: but `user-error` will suppress many errors right? i wanted to suppress only this error, because this error is just a typo mistake, and not an error as such....

Comment: I'm not suggesting to add `user-error` to `debug-ignored-errors` (it's already there by default right now), but to make this particular error use `user-error` (so that it gets ignored by default).